# CSS. Position and overflow

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

I have created a simple demo of my problem.

```css
.set-overflow{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.set-relative{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.element{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -20px;
  background: yellow;
}
.set-overflow:hover .element{
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-overflow">
  <div class="set-relative">
    <div class="element">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two parents and element, which should appear on parent's hover. The problem is that I have to get rid of scroll without changing parents' properties.

Please note that it is just a simple example, so I have to solve this with minimum possible effect on the other elements. Thanks!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o0abLxek/15/

Comment: I didn't get that you want to use a transition on this element. Updated my answer, maybe it helps...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited answer:** Learning that you want to use a transition on the element (I'm guessing you want to make it slide up), I've updated my answer. `height` won't help you as you can't use `transition` on `height`, but you could use `max-height` instead, as pointed out [in this question (How can I transition height: 0; to height: auto; using CSS?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css).

```css
.set-overflow{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.set-relative{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.element{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: yellow;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}
.set-overflow:hover .element{
  max-height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-overflow">
  <div class="set-relative">
    <div class="element">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Old answer:** Instead of moving the element around on hover, why don't you use plain old `visibility`? Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/wpxehqkb/

Comment: Or display, that was my first thought as well. But maybe they want to add a transition to make it “move in” later on or sth. like that.

Answer (score 2):

make your child element to be `height:0` on non-hover state:

```css
.set-overflow{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.set-relative{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
.element{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  background: yellow;
}
.set-overflow:hover .element{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="set-overflow">
  <div class="set-relative">
    <div class="element">content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I want to use transition, so this solution is not what I need